# ViewPager and ListView in its layers

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-listview, android-viewpager

I apologize in advance for my terrible English.

My app should have 6 pages, and each of them will have a **ListView** with its own text.
The list consists of two **TextView**, so I made my own adapter for it:

**BoxAdapter.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class BoxAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context ctx;
    LayoutInflater lInflater;
    ArrayList<Kek> objects;


    BoxAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Kek> products) {
        ctx = context;
        objects = products;
        lInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    // кол-во элементов
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return objects.size();
    }


    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return objects.get(position);
    }


    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
        }

        Kek p = getProduct(position);


        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1)).setText(p.pozic);
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1_2)).setText(p.name);

        return view;
    }



    Kek getProduct(int position) {
        return ((Kek) getItem(position));
    }




}
```

And auxiliary class for him:

**Kek.java**

```
public class Kek {

    String name;
    String pozic;




    Kek(String _pozic,String _describe) {

        pozic = _pozic;
        name = _describe;
    }
}
```

Next for * * ViewPager* * I also created my adapter:

**SlideAdapter.java**

```
package com.github.helpme;



import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;

import java.util.List;

public class SlideAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private List<Fragment> fragmentList;

    public SlideAdapter (FragmentManager fragmentManager, List<Fragment> fragmentList) {
        super(fragmentManager);
        this.fragmentList = fragmentList;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragmentList.size();
    }
}
```

So far I have created 2 test sheets:

**Activity_main_1.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView222"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:text="НУ РАБОТАЙ ЖЕ ТЫ"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.004" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lvMain_1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:divider="@null"></ListView>
    </LinearLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and class

**Layout_1.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;


public class Layout_1 extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main_1, container,false);
        return viewGroup;
    }
}
```

On the same analogy created 2nd page:

**Activity_main_2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView222"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:text="ЧУХ_ЧУХ"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.004" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lvMain_1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:divider="@null"></ListView>
    </LinearLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and class

**Layout_2.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;


public class Layout_2 extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main_2, container,false);
        return viewGroup;
    }
}
```

And finally the main activity:

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.github.helpme;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.PagerAdapter;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private SlideAdapter slideAdapter;
       private ListView lvMain;
       private BoxAdapter boxAdapter;
    ArrayList<Kek> products = new ArrayList<Kek>();
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        List<Fragment> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new Layout_1());
        list.add(new Layout_2());
        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.rader);
        slideAdapter = new SlideAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),list);
        viewPager.setAdapter(slideAdapter);



        fillData();
        boxAdapter = new BoxAdapter(this, products);

        lvMain = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvMain_1);
        lvMain.setAdapter(boxAdapter);


    }



    // генерируем данные для адаптера
    void fillData() {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
            products.add(new Kek (i + ")", "Product " + i));
        }
    }





}
```

If you now run the application it will not start, and in the logs you will see:

> 2019-08-18 09:26:53.879 7138-7138/com.github.helpme E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.github.helpme, PID: 7138
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.github.helpme/com.github.helpme.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3260)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3396)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2009)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7319)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:934)
>        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
>           at com.github.helpme.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:45)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7783)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7772)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3235)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3396) 
>           at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2009) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7319) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:934)

When I saw this, I tried to move the loading of the list to the layer classes * * ViewPager**

```
private ListView lvMain;
           private BoxAdapter boxAdapter;
        ArrayList<Kek> products = new ArrayList<Kek>();
        fillData();
            boxAdapter = new BoxAdapter(this, products);

            lvMain = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvMain_1);
            lvMain.setAdapter(boxAdapter);
    void fillData() {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
                products.add(new Kek (i + ")", "Product " + i));
            }
        }
```

But the compiler directly in the code gave an error:

> BoxAdapter (android.content.Context, ArrayList) in
>   BoxAdapter cannot be applied to (com.github.helpme.Layout_1,
>   ArrayList)

So we got to the essence of this post: How to make Pager sheets with your list inside and how to fill it all.

UDP:

new error:

> 08-11 15:21:02.956 3653-3653/? E/ActivityThread: Service
>   com.android.email.service.EmailBroadcastProcessorService has leaked
>   ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.am@92c8ab8 that was
>   originally bound here android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service
>   com.android.email.service.EmailBroadcastProcessorService has leaked
>   ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.am@92c8ab8 that was
>   originally bound here at
>   android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.(LoadedApk.java:1092) at
>   android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:986) at
>   android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1303) at
>   android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1286) at
>   android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:604) at
>   com.android.emailcommon.service.ak.a(SourceFile:181) at
>   com.android.emailcommon.service.ak.e(SourceFile:224) at
>   com.android.email.service.n.c(SourceFile:177) at
>   com.android.email.provider.b.a(SourceFile:198) at
>   com.android.email.provider.b.a(SourceFile:142) at
>   com.android.email.service.EmailBroadcastProcessorService.c(SourceFile:349)
>   at
>   com.android.email.service.EmailBroadcastProcessorService.onHandleIntent(SourceFile:1334)
>   at
>   android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:66)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) at
>   android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)

Comment: The second approach is correct for your setup. Your `BoxAdapter` needs a `Context` for the first constructor argument, and a `Fragment` is not a `Context`, so replace `this` with `getActivity()` – i.e., `new BoxAdapter(getActivity(), products)`. You will also need to call `findViewById()` on the `Fragment`'s `View`. If you moved that code into `onCreateView()`, then you'd call it on `viewGroup` – i.e., `viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.lvMain_1)`.

Comment: Now the application of course started, but the list still does not appear, and in the logs there is a new error, I added it to the end of the post.

Comment: I do not know how but rewriting the xml file I got rid of the error, thank you very much for your help.